# Integrating twitter bootstrap and using "Base CSS/ form/ Validation states"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate twitter bootstrap into my app. However I noticed the behavior of my app is different from the twitter bootstrap showcase...

I am in reference to the **`Base CSS/ form/ Validation states`** section.

For instance, the following

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on">@</span> <input type="text" name="member.email" value="" id="email" autofocus="autofocus" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

does not render inline but instead as follows:

[image: screen capture]

I am not sure what I got wrong. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give is from the ["Preppended and Appended Inputs"](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) section and it does not include a label in the example.  However, assuming that by "*render inline*" you mean have the label adjacent to the input control, that can be achieved using the `form-horizontal` class on the form itself.